# Setting up MapLibre, osm2pgsql and Martin Tile Server

Tags: osm2pgsql, maplibre-gl

I want to display dynamic maps served by the Martin tile server.

TLDR: I don't know if the bug comes from the MapLibre code or the Martin tile server. I just created a repo for testing, it tries to display a MapLibre map of Brussels City based on the Belgium `mbtiles` file from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.osm.pbf

https://github.com/BigBoulard/martin-test

Here is what I did so far:

### 1. Frontend Test Page with a minimal  `osm-style.json`

I started from an existing style.json and changed the reference to my tile server (Martin):

```json
"sources": {
    "osm-tiles": {
      "type": "vector",
      "tiles": [
        "https://mygateway:8080/martin/planet_osm_line/{z}/{x}/{y}",
        "https://mygateway:8080/martin/planet_osm_point/{z}/{x}/{y}",
        "https://mygateway:8080/martin/planet_osm_polygon/{z}/{x}/{y}",
        "https://mygateway:8080/martin/planet_osm_roads/{z}/{x}/{y}"
      ],
      "minzoom": 0,
      "maxzoom": 22
    }
  },
```

then I changed the `source` and `source-layer` fields in each layer trying to guess if the data is a point, line, polygon, or road and reference the source (i`planet_osm_polygon` below):

```json
"source": "osm-tiles",
"source-layer": "planet_osm_polygon",
```

```js
var map = new maplibregl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: '/osm-style.json',
    center: [4.3601755242029885, 50.85819161299564], // brussels
    zoom: 13 // starting zoom
});
```

**osm-style.json**

```json
{
  "version": 8,
  "sources": {
    "osm-tiles": {
      "type": "vector",
      "tiles": [
        "https://mygateway:8080/martin/planet_osm_line/{z}/{x}/{y}",
        "https://mygateway:8080/martin/planet_osm_point/{z}/{x}/{y}",
        "https://mygateway:8080/martin/planet_osm_polygon/{z}/{x}/{y}",
        "https://mygateway:8080/martin/planet_osm_roads/{z}/{x}/{y}"
      ],
      "minzoom": 0,
      "maxzoom": 22
    }
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "background",
      "type": "background",
      "paint": {
        "background-color": "#f8f4f0"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "water",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "osm-tiles",
      "source-layer": "planet_osm_polygon",
      "filter": ["all", ["!=", "intermittent", 1], ["!=", "brunnel", "tunnel"]],
      "layout": {"visibility": "visible"},
      "paint": {"fill-color": "hsl(210, 67%, 85%)"}
    }    
  ]
}
```

### 2. Creation of an `osm` database with ownership to an `osm-user`

### 3. Import of the `belgium-latest.osm.pbf` file into postgres

```sh
osm2pgsql -c -d osm -U osm_user -H localhost -P 5432 -W -C 2000 belgium-latest.osm.pbf
```

### 4. Ran `Martin Tile Server` in debug mod and check that tiles can be served

When I hit `http://0.0.0.0:3000/catalog`, I see that Martin finds `postgres` tables, sprites and fonts.

```json
{
  "tiles": {
    "planet_osm_line": {
      "content_type": "application/x-protobuf",
      "description": "public.planet_osm_line.way"
    },
    "planet_osm_point": {
      "content_type": "application/x-protobuf",
      "description": "public.planet_osm_point.way"
    },
    "planet_osm_polygon": {
      "content_type": "application/x-protobuf",
      "description": "public.planet_osm_polygon.way"
    },
    "planet_osm_roads": {
      "content_type": "application/x-protobuf",
      "description": "public.planet_osm_roads.way"
    }
  },
  "sprites": {
    "my_sprites": {
      "images": [...]
    }
  },
  "fonts": {...}
}
```

### Problem

Here is what I get when the test page loads:
[image: buggy map]

There's no shape and I'm not supposed to see that much water around Brussels.

#### Martin Logs after upon page load

```sh
2024-03-07 11:35:48 [2024-03-07T10:35:48Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 192.168.65.1 "GET /planet_osm_roads/13/4196/2747 HTTP/1.1" 200 13889 "https://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.111819
2024-03-07 11:35:48 [2024-03-07T10:35:48Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 192.168.65.1 "GET /planet_osm_point/13/4194/2747 HTTP/1.1" 200 11677 "https://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.120157
2024-03-07 11:35:49 [2024-03-07T10:35:49Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 192.168.65.1 "GET /planet_osm_roads/13/4195/2748 HTTP/1.1" 200 25702 "https://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.159577
2024-03-07 11:35:49 [2024-03-07T10:35:49Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 192.168.65.1 "GET /planet_osm_line/13/4196/2748 HTTP/1.1" 200 24327 "https://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.168348
2024-03-07 11:35:49 [2024-03-07T10:35:49Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 192.168.65.1 "GET /planet_osm_line/13/4194/2746 HTTP/1.1" 200 25263 "https://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.174563
2024-03-07 11:35:49 [2024-03-07T10:35:49Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 192.168.65.1 "GET /planet_osm_polygon/13/4195/2747 HTTP/1.1" 200 26338 "https://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.177000
2024-03-07 11:35:49 [2024-03-07T10:35:49Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 192.168.65.1 "GET /planet_osm_polygon/13/4194/2748 HTTP/1.1" 200 27261 "https://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.178879
2024-03-07 11:35:49 [2024-03-07T10:35:49Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 192.168.65.1 "GET /planet_osm_polygon/13/4196/2746 HTTP/1.1" 200 31472 "https://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.190088
2024-03-07 11:35:49 [2024-03-07T10:35:49Z INFO  actix_web::middleware::logger] 192.168.65.1 "GET /planet_osm_point/13/4195/2746 HTTP/1.1" 200 10210 "https://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.050309
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues.

1. The best method to test self-served tiles with `Martin` is to generate the tiles with `Planetiler` first which produces an `mbtiles` file that Martin can use as a source to serve.
2. Then, a JSON endpoint must be referenced into the style, and
   there are several possibilities, but the easiest one is to use a
   single source URL referencing the mbtile file like this:

```json
 "osmtiles":
    {  
       "type": "vector",
       "tiles": ["http://0.0.0.0:3000/belgium/{z}/{x}/{y}"],
       "minzoom": 0,    
       "maxzoom": 22
    }
```

... and in the style layers refers to the identifier of the `osmstyle` source like this

```json
"source": "osmtiles"
```